# fill pandas missing places with different method for different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and I want the final output dataframe `final_df` as

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   Date symbol  cost  prev
0    10      a    30     9
1    10      b    33    10
2    12      a    25     4
3    13      a    29     5

In [18]: final_df
Out[18]: 
   Date symbol  cost  prev
0    10      a  30.0   9.0
1    10      b  33.0  10.0
2    11      a   0.0   9.0
3    11      b   0.0  10.0
4    12      a  25.0   4.0
5    13      a  29.0   5.0
6    14      a   0.0   5.0

In [19]: dates=[10,11,12,13,14]
```

That is as you can see I want to fill up the missing dates and fill the corresponding values with `0` for `cost` column but for column `prev` I want to fill it with the value from previous date. As the single date may contains multiple `symbol` I am using the `pivot_table`.

If I use the `ffill`

```
In [12]: df.pivot_table(index="Date",columns="symbol").reindex(dates,method="ffill").stack().reset_index()
Out[12]: 
   Date symbol  cost  prev
0    10      a  30.0   9.0
1    10      b  33.0  10.0
2    11      a  30.0   9.0
3    11      b  33.0  10.0
4    12      a  25.0   4.0
5    13      a  29.0   5.0
6    14      a  29.0   5.0
```

This gives almost final data structure (it has 7 rows as `final_df`) except for `cost` column where it copies previous data but I want `0` there.

So I tried to fill missing values of different columns with different  method, but that gives a problem, like

```
In [13]: df1=df.pivot_table(index="Date",columns="symbol").reindex(dates)

In [14]: df1["cost"]=df1["cost"].fillna(0)

In [15]: df1["prev"]=df1["prev"].ffill()

In [16]: df1.stack().reset_index()
Out[16]: 
   Date symbol  cost  prev
0    10      a  30.0   9.0
1    10      b  33.0  10.0
2    11      a   0.0   9.0
3    11      b   0.0  10.0
4    12      a  25.0   4.0
5    12      b   0.0  10.0
6    13      a  29.0   5.0
7    13      b   0.0  10.0
8    14      a   0.0   5.0
9    14      b   0.0  10.0
```

As you can see in output there is data with `symbol` `"b"` for date `12,13,14` but I don't want that because in initial dataframe there was no data data with `symbol` `"b"` for date `12,13` and I want to keep it that way and also there must not be one in new date `14` as it follows `13`.

So how can I solve this problem and get the `final_df` output?

**EDIT**

Here is another example to check the program.

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   Date symbol  cost  prev
0    10      a    30     9
1    10      b    33    10
2    14      a    29     5

In [18]: dates=range(10,17)

In [19]: final_df
Out[19]: 
    Date symbol  cost  prev
0     10      a    30     9
1     10      b    33    10
2     11      a     0     9
3     11      b     0    10
4     12      a     0     9
5     12      b     0    10
6     13      a     0     9
7     13      b     0    10
8     14      a    29     5
9     15      a     0     5
10    16      a     0     5
```

**Solution**

I have found this way to the problem. Here I using a trick that keeps track of the missing places in in the initial `pivot_table` and removes finally.

```
In [44]: df1=df.pivot_table(index="Date",columns='symbol',fill_value="missing").reindex(dates)

In [45]: df1["cost"]= df1["cost"].fillna(0)

In [46]: df1["prev"]=df1["prev"].ffill()

In [47]: df1.stack().replace(to_replace="missing",value=np.nan).dropna().reset_index()
Out[47]: 
    Date symbol  cost  prev
0     10      a  30.0   9.0
1     10      b  33.0  10.0
2     11      a   0.0   9.0
3     11      b   0.0  10.0
4     12      a   0.0   9.0
5     12      b   0.0  10.0
6     13      a   0.0   9.0
7     13      b   0.0  10.0
8     14      a  29.0   5.0
9     15      a   0.0   5.0
10    16      a   0.0   5.0
```

Comment: Is this last example the expected output?

Comment: Yess.. missing date will follow the previous available date if there is 2 symbol `a` and `b` available there will be two in new date if one available there will be one

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.  In an effort to be helpful, you're conditions are not well stated.  I'm still unclear on why 'b' gets pulled forward to date 12 when it only had data for date 10.  Maybe you think you did articulate that well enough, but I could not follow the grammar.  Good luck.

Comment: well I think I have found a way. I am adding that to the post. Check if it is a good or bad way and also suggest it be more efficient

Comment: @Eular Do you know why there were missing lines/values in the input table?